# Avoid the AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'ranges'

Tags: python, openpyxl, attributeerror

I want to edit an Excel spreadsheet using openpyxl. and unmerge all the combined cells in the document in order to read the whole sheet with more precision and then save it in a new file. The following is the code I am using:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

base_folder = '/Users/esparaquia/Projects/readExcel'

test_file = 'BookTest.xlsm'
wb = load_workbook(filename=os.path.join(base_folder, test_file))
ws = wb['Sheet1']

# unmerge all the cells
while ws.merged_cells.ranges != []:
   # unmerge all the merged_cells
   for merged in ws.merged_cells.ranges:
      ws.unmerge_cells(str(merged))

# forward fill in every row based on border properties
value = ''
for irow, row in enumerate(ws.rows):

   # only worry about the first few rows (the headers)
   if irow < 2:

       for cell in row:
           # check if there is a left border (that it starts a header block)
           if multi_getattr(cell, 'border.left.color.tint') or cell.col_idx == 1:
              value = cell.value

           # fill in an empty space
           if cell.value is None or cell.value == '':
              cell.value = value

# save the modified file
temp_file = 'tmp.xlsx'
wb.save(filename=os.path.join(base_folder, temp_file))
```

And this is the error I'm getting when I run this code:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-96fa676a9b5d> in <module>()
      12 # unmerge all the cells
----> 13 while ws.merged_cells.ranges != []:
      14     # unmerge all the merged_cells
      15     for merged in ws.merged_cells.ranges:
      16         ws.unmerge_cells(str(merged))

AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'ranges'
```

In the line:

```
while ws.merged_cells.ranges != []:
```

I would greatly appreciate your help, I am starting with Python and I still do not have a good eye to see these errors

Comment: Please share the full Traceback

Comment: If you set a variable to `ws.merged_cells`, what do you see in the variable explorer when you look at that variable?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `ws.merged_cells` is a `set` and this Object does not have any range attribute, todo something similar you should probably do:

```
while ws.merged_cells.ranges != set():
```

Because `set()` is the empty set object

Comment: Is still the same problem, I get the same error with `set()`, so the as I defined in the beginning `[]` I'm not declaring an empty object?

Comment: `[]` is the empty list in python, so this is an object

Comment: output `print(type(ws.merged_cells.ranges))` please

Comment: This doesn't make sense. The error is coming from trying access the attribute `ranges` from `ws.merged_cells`. How is changing what that is compared change anything, when the error comes before the comparison?

Comment: Printing the line I get: `---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-3e8ba118c566> in <module>()
----> 1 print(type(ws.merged_cells.ranges))

AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'ranges'
`